# How to convert 'O' values to date format

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have tried to convert a column with 'O' values like

```
31 October 2020
31 October 2020
31 October 2020
30 November 2020
30 November 2020
```

in a date format:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce', format='%m %d %Y')
```

However I've got `NaT` values instead of 10/31/2020 and 11/30/2020. After using the code, the type is `dtype('<M8[ns]')`.

Can you explain me where the error is?

Comment: Your format given in the code is not the format given in your example data.

Comment: The format parameter dictates the incoming string format not the output format.  The output of to_datime is a datetime dtype.  change to `format='%d %B %Y"`.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d %B %Y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: @Math Hrm... Try this before the to_datetime `df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.strip()`  You might have whitespace issues in  your data.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: You have something very strange going on.  Upgrade pandas, run the exact code below.  If that runs then you more than likely have a data issue.  I the exact code below doesn't run then you have installation issue with python pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

inputtxt = StringIO("""Date
31 October 2020
31 October 2020
31 October 2020
30 November 2020
30 November 2020""")

df = pd.read_csv(inputtxt)
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d %B %Y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
               Date       Date2
0   31 October 2020  10/31/2020
1   31 October 2020  10/31/2020
2   31 October 2020  10/31/2020
3  30 November 2020  11/30/2020
4  30 November 2020  11/30/2020
```